# Wordpress problem with Real Cookie Banner: Namespace blocked to access REST-API through NGINX Config

Tags: json, wordpress, rest, nginx

I am using Wordpress Version 6.4.3 with the Real Cookie Banner Plugin. I can't access the Banner setting in the wordpress backend, as something is blocking the access to the REST-API.

I get following error messages.
in the Browser-Console:
Fetch API cannot load https://example.com/wp-json/real-queue/v1/...

in Wordpress:
[GET] /wp-json/real-queue/v1/status; TypeError: Load failed

I am using the Raidboxes hosting with an Nginx server config. If somebody has an idea how to whitelist the json-namespace to access the REST-API, that would be great!

I checked that the access is not caused by my ad blocker, that there are no security plugins activated that can cause the error, and I contacted the raid boxes support to be sure, that the API access is not blocked by the server.

Comment: There are multiple reasons why the REST API fails. The team behind Real Cookie Banner also has a knowledge base article about this [here](https://devowl.io/knowledge-base/wordpress-rest-api-does-not-respond/). Additionally, please check your PHP error log if something got logged.